# How to install Brutal doom redemption?

Tags: doom

I have installed Doom Classic Complete from steam (I am running Windows 8):

http://store.steampowered.com/sub/18397/

Now I would like to try:

http://www.moddb.com/mods/brutal-doom-redemption

which I have downloaded. First I have downloaded and unpacked:
http://devbuilds.drdteam.org/gzdoom/

[image]

Next I have extracted Brutal Doom Redemption to that same folder above:

[image]

But when I run gzdoom.exe it just starts up as before. How do I load Doom Brutal Redemption MOD?

**EDIT/SOLUTION:**

Seems the solution is just to drag **BDJR.pk3.bak** onto **gzdoom.exe**:

[image]

Comment: Are you on germany by chance? AFAIK german versions have gore reduction.

Comment: Nope, the point is that I just get the same menu, it does not seem that Redemption is being run at all.

Comment: `gzdoom.exe -file […].PK3` doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Try to locate the `.ini` config file and edit it:

There should be section `[Global.Autoload]`. Put there a complete path to these two mods (I am assuming here that brutal doom is in `brutalv20b.pk3` and Redemption in `BDJR.pk3.bak` ) :

```
[Global.Autoload]
Path=[PATH-TO-FILE]/brutalv20b.pk3
Path=[PATH-TO-FILE]/BDJR.pk3.bak
```